# SSRS Page x of 0 after upgrade from SQL Server 2008 to 2012

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, sql-server-2012

Running into an issue where after upgrading SQL Server from 2008/R2 to 2012, SSRS report when rendered to PDF will display "Page x of 0" at the bottom (x = page number of report).  This only occurs in PDF.

I open the reports, and the correct usage of the global parameters is there.  If I re-deploy the report to the upgraded SSRS, it works fine.

It appears to be an upgrade issue.  Applying the SQL Server 2012 SP1 doesn't help either.

Any ideas?

Comment: What global variable are you using to define total pages?

Comment: +1 as I could face the same issue in the future.:) Do you mean: *`If I re-deploy the report to the upgraded SSRS, it works fine.`* , if you re-deploy into UN-UPGREADED SSRS?

Comment: @beargle - I am using:
="Page " & Globals!PageNumber & " of " & Globals!TotalPages

Comment: @bonCodigo - If you take the original report from BIDS/Report Builder and upload the report into you newly upgraded SQL Server 2012 with SSRS, and then run the report. Viola! It works fine.  I dont modify or edit the RDL in any way.  Just re-upload it back to the SSRS server which was upgraded to 2012.

Comment: Since it sounds like you're only interested in counting total pages, you may have more consistent results with `Globals!OverallTotalPages`. This was introduced in SQL Server 2008 R2 and is only available for report headers and footers.

See [`Globals` collection documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255216(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: @beargle - yes, for future reports.  However, all of the 200+ reports previously developed in SQL 2005, should get upgraded properly.  At this point, it's just easier to re-deploy the report solution and be done with it. I think others were hoping to just apply a SQL patch or update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we opened a ticket with MS.  In a nutshell, when running an in-place upgrade, the RDL's stored in the ReportServer DB are "left alone".  Because MS changed only the Globals!TotalPages to Globals!OverAllTotalPages and the RDL's are never touched during the upgrade process, the error occurs.

This also explains why when you take the un-modified original report and re-upload/deploy the report. It works.

This is fine if your just updating you local server.  When you have 4500+ installations which can support up to N users, and 180+ reports.  We get a trouble ticket in when a customer upgrades.  That can be a lot of trouble tickets.

Not sure why MS just didn't "upgrade" the Globals!TotalPages to Globals!OverAllTotalPages.  Didn't get an answer for that one.

Comment: To follow up on this, we got this hotfix approved and is now available for both 2008R2 and 2012!